# htaccess slug 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a php website where pages are linked by slug (Ex. mysqite.com/slug).

For slugs like '**home**', '**about-us**', '**contact**', '**my-result**' etc it's working fine but for some slugs like '**result**', '**about**' a 404 (not found) error displayed. How I resolve this issue?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /institution/http/
RewriteRule departments(|[a-zA-Z0-9_\-/]+)$ department.php?page=$1
RewriteRule stream/(|[a-zA-Z0-9_\-/]+)$ post.php?page=$1
RewriteRule faculty/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-/]+)$ new_post.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+)$ index.php?page=$1

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have **about.php** and **result.php** files already existing in the same directory. The slug(s) match the file name(s). If so, please try:

Edit your first line to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

Remove the line:

```
RewriteRule .* $0.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You fix this in your CMS, so that you either redirect to the correct slug or create pages for "result" and "about". Otherwise you can do this right in your htaccess file:

Add this right below `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteRule ^about$ /about-us [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^result$ /my-result [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you Jon Lin for your suggestion. I can definitely allocate separate pages for about and result.

But why the 'about' or the 'result' slug does not work individually (ex. mysite.com/cms/about)? According to my .htaccess rules, these will be redirected to index.php?page=about & index.php?page=result respectively.

Any idea?